# Вывести элемент при клике на jQuery

Tags: jquery

На телефоне какой-то элемент перекрывает блоки и возможности узнать нету, так как *firebug* и т.д нету. Как можно на *jQuery* сделать, чтобы при клике в область он показал мне `alert'ом` самый верхний элемент в этой точке?

Answer (score 2):

Делается так. Ключевое - `e.stopPropagation();`

```js
$('div').on('click', function(e){
  $(e.target).css('background', 'red');
  alert($(e.target).attr('class'));
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Первый <div class="first">
  Второй <div class="second">
    Третий <div class="third"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не стоит всегда скрывать сниппет :-) обычно сворачивание стоит добавлять когда много кода, либо когда их несколько. В данном случае - лучше оставить его открытым чтобы сразу было видно решение

Comment: @Grundy оки, есть такая мысль.